# Fedora + Cinnamon - How to display "uninstall" entry in Cinnamon context menu?

Tags: fedora, cinnamon

When I use Linux Mint, I have the **uninstall** option in the Cinnamon context menu (see screenshot)

When I use Fedora 37 + Cinnamon, I don't have this entry in the context menu.

I think Fedora hides the **uninstall** entry on purpose.

How can I re-enable the **uninstall** entry in Fedora + Cinnamon ?

[image]

Comment: Every Cinnamon DE I run, except for Mint, does not have this feature. I did find an Arch AUR package that enabled this, but nothing for Fedora.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a mint specific feature that might not even be part of upstream cinnamon! I honestly don't know whether it is, but that uninstall button requires quite some distribution-specific code to work, and it would seem unlikely that anyone would disable it once they've implemented that code